# Document.write(variable.toDateString); not working

Tags: javascript

```
document.write('test');
```

Will work, and print 'test' to the document.

```
document.write(d.toDateString());
```

Does nothing. d is my Date variable of course, but it simply isn't printing out the date as I assume it should. Probably an amateur error :(. Also I'd like to print that date out in a red colour, how do I do that?

Edit: My full code (I think the conversion of milliseconds is making it act out of the norm, but I need to do that. How do I convert it all back or something?)

```
var birthYear = parseInt(prompt ('Enter your birth year:'));
var birthMonth = prompt ('Enter the name of the month of birth:');
var birthDay = parseInt(prompt ('Enter your day of birth as an integer:'));
var milliDay = 1000*60*60*24; //Milliseconds in a day
monthAbb = 'janfebmaraprmayjunjulaugsepoctnovdec';
chineseZod = 12;
zodCycle = 1924; //Chinese Zodiac Cycle
var zodAnimal = new Array('Rat','Ox','Tiger','Rabbit','Dragon','Snake','Horse','Goat','Monkey','Rooster','Dog','Pig');
var zodAnimalD = new Array('Forthright, tenacious, intense, meticulous, charismatic, sensitive, intellectual, industrious, charming, eloquent, sociable, artistic, and shrewd.  Can be manipulative, vindictive, self-destructive, envious, mendacious, venal, obstinate, critical, over-ambitious, ruthless, intolerant, and scheming.','Dependable, ambitious, calm, methodical, born leader, patient, hardworking, conventional, steady, modest, logical, resolute, and tenacious.  Can be stubborn, dogmatic, hot-tempered, narrow-minded, materialistic, rigid, and demanding.','Unpredictable, rebellious, colorful, powerful, passionate, daring, impulsive, vigorous, stimulating, sincere, affectionate, humanitarian, and generous.  Can be restless, reckless, impatient, quick-tempered, obstinate, selfish, aggressive, and moody.','Gracious, good friend, kind, sensitive, soft-spoken, amiable, elegant, reserved, cautious, artistic, thorough, tender, self-assured, shy, astute, compassionate, lucky, and flexible.  Can be moody, detached, superficial, self-indulgent, opportunistic, and stubborn.','Magnanimous, stately, vigorous, strong, self-assured, proud, noble, direct, dignified, eccentric, intellectual, fiery, passionate, decisive, pioneering, artistic, generous, and loyal.  Can be tactless, arrogant, imperious, tyrannical, demanding, intolerant, dogmatic, violent, impetuous, and brash.','Deep thinker, wise, mystic, graceful, soft-spoken, sensual, creative, prudent, shrewd, elegant, cautious, responsible, calm, strong, constant, and purposeful.  Can be a loner, bad communicator, possessive, hedonistic, self-doubting, distrustful, mendacious, suffocating, and cold.','Cheerful, popular, quick-witted, changeable, earthy, perceptive, talkative, agile, magnetic, intelligent, astute, flexible, and open-minded.  Can be fickle, arrogant, childish, anxious, rude, gullible, and stubborn.','Righteous, sincere, sympathetic, mild-mannered, observant, artistic, intellectual, ingenious, innovative, creative, mothering, peaceful, and generous.  Can be indecisive, over-passive, worrier, pessimistic, sensitive, shy, and weak-willed.','Inventor, motivator, improviser, quick-witted, inquisitive, flexible, innovative, problem solver, self-assured, sociable, artistic, polite, dignified, competitive, objective, and factual.  Can be egotistical, vain, arrogant, selfish, reckless, snobbish, deceptive, manipulative, cunning, jealous, suspicious, and stubborn.','  Acute, neat, meticulous, organized, self-assured, decisive, conservative, critical, perfectionist, alert, zealous, practical, scientific, and responsible.  Can be over zealous and critical, puritanical, egotistical, abrasive, proud, opinionated, and gives into empty bravado.','Honest, intelligent, straightforward, loyal, sense of justice and fair play, attractive, amicable, unpretentious, sociable, open-minded, idealistic, moralistic, practical, affectionate, sensitive, and easy going.  Can be cynical, lazy, cold, judgmental, pessimistic, worrier, stubborn, and quarrelsome.','Honest, gallant, sturdy, sociable, peace-loving, patient, loyal, hard-working, trusting, sincere, calm, understanding, thoughtful, scrupulous, passionate, and intelligent.  Can be naive, over-reliant, self-indulgent, gullible, fatalistic, and materialistic.');
var monthArr = new Array(11);

monthArr [0] = "jan";
monthArr [1] = "feb";
monthArr [2] = "mar";
monthArr [3] = "apr";
monthArr [4] = "may";
monthArr [5] = "jun";
monthArr [6] = "jul";
monthArr [7] = "aug";
monthArr [8] = "sep";
monthArr [9] = "oct";
monthArr [10] = "nov";
monthArr [11] = "dec";



var monthNum = monthAbb.indexOf(birthMonth.slice(0, 3).toLowerCase()) / 3;
alert(monthNum);
var d = new Date (birthYear, monthNum, birthDay);
alert(d);
var dCurrent = new Date();
dCurrent = dCurrent.getTime(); //Grabs the time of the current date in milliseconds.
d = d.getTime(); //Grabs the time of the user-entered date in milliseconds.
var dTotal = dCurrent - d;
alert(dTotal);
dTotal = dTotal / milliDay;
dTotal = Math.floor(dTotal); //7193
alert(dTotal + ' is after division');
dTotal = dTotal / 365.25;
dTotal = Math.floor(dTotal);
alert(dTotal + ' is how old you are!');
dTotal = birthYear - zodCycle;
dTotal = dTotal % chineseZod;
alert(dTotal);
alert(d);
```

Comment: Where are you initializing the date variable? And, did you try this in a separate file from your "main" code, so, you can see if this is the code that's causing the problem?

Comment: Show the full code. In which context you are running this?

Comment: seems legit: http://jsfiddle.net/ftch5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely `d` is not a real date object but something else.

Try this:

```
var d = new Date();
document.write("<span style=\"color: red;\">" + d.toDateString() + "</span>");
```